# Как поставить слой поверх изображения?

Tags: css

Z-index почему то не помогает

```
 <div id="slider">
    <img src="img/slide_1.png" />
 </div>

#slider {
margin: 0 auto;
height: 450px;
width: 1100px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
z-index: 2;
 }

 #slider img {
margin: 0 auto;
height: 450px;
width: 1100px;
z-index: 1;
 }
```

Вот делаю так, по идее rgba слой должен быть поверх изображения по значениям z-index. Но он все же остается под ним.

Как поступить?

Comment: хм, но картинка же внутри #slider. Просто вынесите куда то её. Или доп див добавьте на том же уровне чтобы он был сверху.

Comment: все равно ничего

Comment: Что бы расположить слои друг над другом нужно:
----------------------------------------------------
1) родительский блок с position: relative;

2) собственно сами слои с position: absolute; и свойством z-index которое как раз и будет определять порядок.

в вашем примере картинка будет всегда выше бэкграунда блока, в котором она располагается.

Answer (score 2):

z-index имеет смысл применять только тогда когда у вас у элементов, к которым вы его применяете, свойство position отлично от static ( значения по умолчанию ).
Подробнее читайте [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
#slider:after{
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
z-index:5;
}
```